# Possessive pronouns vs personal pronouns in genitive

Tags: meaning, difference, pronoun

***Seiner*** liegt auf dem Tisch.

***Sein*** liegt auf dem Tisch.

Do you happen to know what is the difference in meaning between personal pronouns in genitive and possessive pronouns? Does the position of the pronoun matter when determining said difference? Thanks.

Comment: Example 2 is grammatically wrong. A substantive is sorely missing, compare to *Sein Schlüssel liegt auf dem Tisch*. Therefore the question would benefit from some clarification.

Comment: Without making clear what "seiner" relates to you wouldn't want to use the first example either - at least not in certain regions. Some dialects treat "seiner" without any reference as code for "[his] penis".

Comment: I vote to close. This question needs clarification.

Comment: My understanding is that the genitive of personal pronouns are rarely used, so rarely that it's questionable whether it's worthwhile learning the inflections for that case. Verbs and prepositions which used to require a genitive have switched to another case, and almost any sentence can be rephrased to use a possessive pronoun instead. Something similar occurs in English; when Sinatra sings "I've got you deep in the heart of me" it's for rhyme and meter, no one would actually say that.

Comment: @guidot I am talking about possessive pronouns, not possesive articles. Refer to "Meine ist jünge als seine." https://www.deutschplus.net/en/pages/Possessivpronomen

Comment: @Rare OK, "seiner" clearly is a possessive pronoun in the deutschplus use of that term. As you can see in their table, it's nominative singular masculine. To use a personal pronoun in genitive you would need a place in a sentence where you can use a genitive. The subject of a sentence can clearly not be in genitive case.

Answer (score 3):

It is the same as in English between "my" and "mine", "your" and "yours", "her" and "hers", etc. You use "seiner" when that is the entirety of the noun phrase, "sein" when it describes what comes after it.

Your second example is grammatically wrong, like "My is lying on the table" would be in English. (It unfortunately doesn't work with "his" because in English those happen to be the same.)